# Фонетический разбор существительных на -ие. Пожалуйста, объясните или помогите найти материал по этой теме

Tags: фонетика

Почему в слове "занятие" при фонетическом разборе все пишут окончание [и] [й'] [э], оно же так не звучит, если внимательно себя прослушать. Как сделать правильно фонетический разбор существительных, оканчивающихся на -ие.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Почему в слове "занятие" при фонетическом разборе все пишут окончание
 [и] [й'] [э]?
```

А кто эти "все"? Вы, может быть , имеете в виду частичную транскрипцию при объяснении окончаний в младших классах, к которой прибегают, чтобы показать скрытый йот? Например, здание - здан[ий’э],  заняти[йэ], заняти[йа],заняти[йу].

Когда делают фонетический разбор слов на -ие, учитывают, что книжная форма - ие , а разговорная  -ье. В транскрипции книжный вариант:[ за(крышечка)н'ат'иjь], разговорный   [за(крышечка)н'ат'jь].